# Integrate $\int_0^\pi \mathrm{d}x \ e^{\mathrm{i}x} \sqrt{1 - e^{2\mathrm{i}x}}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate
$$
\int\limits_0^\pi \mathrm{d}x \ e^{\mathrm{i}x} \sqrt{1 - e^{2\mathrm{i}x}}
$$

I tried using various trigonometric identities but nothing seems to work.
A small hint would be enough.

Comment: Have you tried $t=e^{ix}$?

Comment: ah thanks it worked with $t=e^{ix}$ and then $t = \sin(z)$. Don't know why I didn't try that :/

Comment: Glad you solved your own problem with an insightful comment above. So write up an answer please :). So it does not appear in unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution $u=e^x:$
\begin{equation*}
\int \sqrt{1-u^{2i}}u^{-1+i}du.
\end{equation*}
Now use the substitution $s=u^i:$
\begin{equation*}
-i\int \sqrt{1-s^2}ds.
\end{equation*}
Now use the substitution $s=\sin(p)$ to get:
\begin{equation*}
-i\int \cos^2(p)dp.
\end{equation*}
By writing $\cos^2(p)=\frac{\cos(2p)+1}{2}$ and using the substitution $w=2p,$ we get 
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{i}{4}\int \cos(w)dw-\frac{i}{2}\int 1 dp.
\end{equation*}
Evaluate these two integrals, and begin to re-substitute back. Note that you may need the trig identities
\begin{equation*}
\sin(2p)=2\sin(p)\cos(p),~\cos^2(p)=1-\sin^2(p).~_{\square}
\end{equation*}